# couchdb reduce grouped by key

Tags: php, couchdb

I have a view that returns all documents for a list of tags. The problem is that it returns documents grouped by tag.

```
keys=["tag1","tag2"]

function(doc){
    if(doc.tags){
        for(var i = 0; i < doc.tags.length; i++){
            emit(doc.tags[i], doc);
        }
     }
}
```

returns

```
["rows"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["key"]=> string(4) "tag1" ["value"]=> array(1) { here my list of documents for this tag...
```

How to you transform that into a list of documents with unique ids ?

Comment: Could you explain this a little more?  Are you looking for a list of documents with a given tag?

Comment: yes, exactly, return list of documents for given tags

Comment: Do you mean you want something akin to "select unique doc where  doc.tags contains 'tag1' and 'tag2'"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **startkey** and **endkey** arguments to your view query.
For example to retrieve only documents with "tag1", use:

> GET .../_view/your-view-name?startkey="tag1"&endkey="tag1"

Your view, behind the scenes, will create a "secondary index" (a B-tree actually).
This means a list of all "emitted" rows, sorted by its key. This allows for very efficient lookups, and retrieval of subsets, of adjacent rows.

The trick is to create views that place the subsets your interested on, on adjacent rows.

See the example here:
[Finding many; from CouchDB the definitive guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html#many)
Read this blog, about creating very smart indexes: [CouchDB joins](http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2007/10/couchdb-joins)

Comment: I'm pust POST with keys param, startkey is not working in my case

Comment: Did you try a GET, with params in the URL?

Comment: it says startkey and key are incompatible

Comment: @Eric, you need to read the documentation linked in my answer.    
If you use `key=tag1`, you'll be retrieving only documents matching `tag1`.  
If you use `startkey` and/or `endkey` you'll be retrieving all tags between that range. Remember that the view will sort the documents according to your key.

Comment: Thanks, I'll validate your answer. Since then I went for Mongodb  which is more practical for my data structure, so I can't test...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a query along the lines of "select unique doc where doc.tags contains 'tag1' and 'tag2'", you could consider using [CouchDB-Lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene/). You could have an index along the lines of

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.tags){        
    var result = new Document();
    for(var i = 0; i < doc.tags.length; i++){
        result.add(doc.tags[i], {"field":"tag"});
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

you would likely want to have it use the "keyword" analyzer as well.

You could then query it using e.g.

```
http://localhost:5984/_fti/local/dbname/_design/foo/view_name?q=tag%3Atag1%20AND%20tag%3Atag2
```

I can't think of a way to do it with "vanilla" CouchDB unless you want to de-duplicate on the client or have very large indexes (i.e. have every tag combination indexed) which obviously won't scale well if you have lots of tags.